# how to "fdisk -l" excluding snap

Tags: usb, mount, fdisk

Before using dd to write a bootable ISO to a USB drive, I would like to be certain that I have the correct device. My plan was to list all devices, using fdisk -l, before and after inserting the USB device. Then I simply use diff to find the additional device entry and I know where I am.

But these days, fdisk -l generates tons of output (with single records spread across multiple lines) for snap software. This, of course, messes with my plan.

Can I get fdisk -l to elide loopback devices? I searched for "loop", and also "snap" in the manpage, but found nothing.

Any other suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the device name in the command. This example will give you (only) all of the **/dev/sdX** devices:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd?
```

Comment: That's a huge improvement, thanks. It seems to generate a lot of redundant output still, but it's a lot more manageable than the dozens of snaps!

Comment: You can add multiple arguments to the device list if you need to. I have some Veracrypt containers, so I can add `/dev/mapper/V*` to get them as well.

Comment: Close enough and no further offers, so I'll mark as "the answer" thanks for taking the time :)